# Django Celery task to continue after error/exception

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celery-task

I have a celery task that loops through a list of receivers to send a message. If any of the send calls fail, I dont want the celery task to exit, but instead continue with the other items in the loop.

This does not happen with task.retry(throw=False) in my case. I do see the task exiting at that point without doing blah or even iterating through the loop further.

I dont want chords or chains, it is not a parallel task execution. How can I accomplish this ?

```
@celery_app.task()

def send_msg_to_list():

    for recvr in Emailrecvr.objects.filter(query=obj):
        try:

            email_rv = recvr.send(msg)

        except SMTPException:

            # Dont exit the loop but continue with others 
            send_msg_to_list.retry(throw=False)

    # do some blah here
```

Comment: Don't retry. Simply `pass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
celery_app.task()
def send_msg_to_list():

    for recvr in Emailrecvr.objects.filter(query=obj):
        try:

            email_rv = recvr.send(msg)

        except SMTPException:

            # Dont exit the loop but continue with others 
            pass
```